# Dev environment for smart client application

Tags: .net, winforms, development-environment

we are starting a new smart client project, which is .net winform as client, connecting web service at application server in win 2003. currently, all developers are using win xp pro, to enalbe debugging at both client and server side, we try to get both client and web service installed on XP pc, but the web server require service account to be used for authentication to Active Directory which need IIS6, so it won't work on XP(xp only support IIS5). What is best way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you mean by "Active Directory which need IIS6". I worked on a classic ASP (not ASP.Net) project years ago running IIS5 under XP which used Active Directory. MSDN has an [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742405.aspx) explaining how to create AD accounts for IIS5.

Please explain in more detail what you are trying to do, and what is not working in IIS5.

Comment: what I mean is that IIS5 run under local ASPNET account, it doesn't have the ability to create APP pool with service account(IIS6). but we have found a workaround which can change the IIS5 meta data to make it running under domain account.